# Customer Logout Observer in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, event-observer

How can I set an event observer for customer logout action in magento2?

Comment: you can see list of all events from this link https://cyrillschumacher.com/magento2-list-of-all-dispatched-events/

Answer (score 5):

you can observe one of the events `controller_action_predispatch_customer_account_logout` or `controller_action_postdispatch_customer_account_logout` depending on when you want to observe things. before loging out or after.

or you can observe the `customer_logout` event for the exact logout moment.

To write an observer you need to create in your module the file `etc/frontend/events.xml` with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="{event_name_here}"> <!-- use one of the events above -->
        <observer name="[namespace]_[module]" instance="[Namespace]\[Module]\Observer\Logout" />
    </event>
</config>
```

then create the file `[Namespace]/[Module]/Observer/Logout.php`

```
<?php 
namespace [Namespace]\[Module]\Observer;

class Logout implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface 
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        //your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: please update the logout code in observer file..

Answer (score 2):

The event name is `customer_logout`

In your custom module create app/code/{Company}/{Module}/etc/frontend/events.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_logout">
        <observer name="{company_module}_customer_logout" instance="{Company}\{Module}\Observer\Frontend\CustomerLogOutObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Then create your observer in {Company}{Module}\Observer\Frontend\CustomerLogOutObserver.php

```
namespace {Company}\{Module}\Observer\Frontend;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class CustomerLogOutObserver implements ObserverInterface
{

    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        //do stuff here
    }
}
```

Take a look at app/code/Magento/Customer/Controller/Account/Logout.php

```
/**
 * Customer logout action
 *
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect
 */
public function execute()
{
    $lastCustomerId = $this->session->getId();
    $this->session->logout()->setBeforeAuthUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl())
        ->setLastCustomerId($lastCustomerId);
 ....
```

Then app/code/Magento/Customer/Model/Session.php

```
/**
 * Logout customer
 *
 * @api
 * @return $this
 */
public function logout()
{
    if ($this->isLoggedIn()) {
        $this->_eventManager->dispatch('customer_logout', ['customer' => $this->getCustomer()]);
        $this->_logout();
....
```