# Magento2: Custom Logout Observer with redirection

Tags: magento2, event-observer, customer, redirect, logout

I'm implementing a SSO extension for Magento2. Right now I want to add an observer to the customer_logout event in order to execute a redirection to my custom logout endpoint.

I followed what is described at [this other question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102536/customer-logout-observer-in-magento2), and also what I saw at [CheckContactUsFormObserver](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Captcha/Observer/CheckContactUsFormObserver.php) class:.

I defined my event file (/etc/frontend/events.xml)

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="customer_logout">
    <observer name="{company_module}_customer_logout" instance="{Company}\{Module}\Observer\Frontend\CustomerLogOutObserver" />
</event>
```

I described my observer in {Company}{Module}\Observer\Frontend\CustomerLogOutObserver.php

```
namespace {Company}\{Module}\Observer\Frontend;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag;
use Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use {Company}\{Module}\Helper\Data;

class CustomerLogOutObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_customerSession;
    protected $_helper;
    protected $_redirect;

    public function __construct(
        Session $customerSession,
        Data $helper,
        ActionFlag $actionFlag,
        RedirectInterface $redirect
    ) {
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->_helper = $helper;
        $this->_actionFlag = $actionFlag;
        $this->_redirect = $redirect;
    }

    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
        $this->_actionFlag->set('', Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
        $this->_redirect->redirect($controller->getResponse(), 'sso/saml2/logout');
    }
}
```

But when I executed it, I got:

```
 Call to a member function getResponse() on a non-object
```

It seems that the getControllerAction returns nothing.

Why a similar code is supoosed to be working for the CheckContactUsFormObserver class and not for me?

Answer (score 4):

the objects you can get from an observer object depend on which objects are passed into it when the event is dispatched.

In the case of customer_logout, only the customer is provided: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/1d97cd9ddee038c9b93c43b74c8e318702a70a33/app/code/Magento/Customer/Model/Session.php#L464

The response seems to be a shared object (since it is not declared as non shared): https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/1f5214730533c4e80f4bf00416aa5a3d82433571/app/etc/di.xml#L18

Given that, you should be able to inject the Object in your constructor using `\Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface` and you should get the actual used response.

```
namespace {Company}\{Module}\Observer\Frontend;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag;
use Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use {Company}\{Module}\Helper\Data;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;

class CustomerLogOutObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_customerSession;
    protected $_helper;
    protected $_redirect;
    protected $_response;

    public function __construct(
        Session $customerSession,
        Data $helper,
        ActionFlag $actionFlag,
        RedirectInterface $redirect,
        ResponseInterface $response
    ) {
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->_helper = $helper;
        $this->_actionFlag = $actionFlag;
        $this->_redirect = $redirect;
        $this->_response = $response;
    }

    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        $this->_actionFlag->set('', Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
        $this->_redirect->redirect($this->_response, 'sso/saml2/logout');
    }
}
```

Let me know if this doesn't work. The response Object might also be created by a factory in a Controller Action. In this cas, it would be another Instance of the Object and you would have to obtain the correct instance

Design hint: for easier maintenance, you should name your observers after the task it does, not after the event it is dispatched from

Comment: I had no errors, but redirection is not working

Comment: ok, i think the problem is, that in the logOut Controller Action, the redirect path is hardcoded: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/Controller/Account/Logout.php#L44. A solution might be, to create an after Plugin on the Logout Controller Action execute method and modify the resultRedirect return value. An explanation on how to use an after Plugin can be found here: http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_object_manager_plugin_system

Comment: It seems quite complex for just a redirection :(
I will try

Comment: currently i see no other way to edit the redirect other then via a plugin or completely replacing the logout controller action

Comment: Really appreciate  your help. with this Plugin then I don't need the observer anymore, right? Can I set a __construct on the Plugin and get the Helpers and the customerSession?

And since I don't want the logout action to take place, make I use beforePlugin rather than afterPlugin?

Comment: yes right, plugins are an additional way in M2 to change the applications behaviour without having to change the actual core code. If an observer does not fit your needs, your next approach should always be using a plugin. Thats a good question, I have to look into this. It should at least be possible to extend the construct method of the original object I think

Comment: it seems, you can define your own constructor in a Plugin: Plugin definition: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/9e78b207b6bd3d641a31d886db1412219baef1ed/app/code/Magento/Catalog/etc/adminhtml/di.xml#L69 The Action\Full class inherits the constructor from here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Indexer/Category/Product/AbstractAction.php#L106 The Plugin itself has its own constructor: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Plugin/Model/Indexer/Category/Product/MaxHeapTableSizeProcessorOnFullReindex.php#L24

Comment: I will try, but in case I keep using the observer, calcultating the url with the helper and executing a PHP redirection [1] directly is consider dirty code?

[1] http://php.net/manual/es/function.header.php

Comment: yes, I think so, since you are bypassing the magento framework logic. There may be some additional tasks that don't get executed anymore when you just enforce this

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I have found a solution by myself by doing a research

> If you want to do that then on __construct() function of your class
>   observer, you must inject two classes.
>
> - First, \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory which responsible for    redirection,
> - Another class \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface which will    make URL for that redirection.
> - Then create object for ResponseFactory    ,and using  setRedirect($YourUrl)->sendResponse(); redirect to your    wished url.

**Observer**

```
<?php
namespace [Vendor]\[modulename]\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class [YourClass] implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory
     */
    private $responseFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
     */
    private $url;

    public function __construct(
        ......
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url,
        ......
    ) {
        $this->responseFactory = $responseFactory;
        $this->url = $url;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $redirectionUrl = $this->url->getUrl('[ModuleName]/[ModuleName]/[[Action]');
        $this->responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($redirectionUrl)->sendResponse();

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Example: In your code

```
namespace {Company}\{Module}\Observer\Frontend;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag;
use Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use {Company}\{Module}\Helper\Data;


class CustomerLogOutObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_customerSession;
    protected $_helper;
    protected $_redirect;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory
     */
    private $responseFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
     */
    private $url;

    public function __construct(
        Session $customerSession,
        Data $helper,
        ActionFlag $actionFlag,
        RedirectInterface $redirect,
       \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url
    ) {
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->_helper = $helper;
        $this->_actionFlag = $actionFlag;
        $this->_redirect = $redirect;
        $this->responseFactory = $responseFactory;
        $this->url = $url;
    }

    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
       $redirectionUrl = $this->url->getUrl( 'sso/saml2/logout');
        $this->responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($redirectionUrl)->sendResponse();
    }
}
```